# How can I upload a file using a Servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, file-upload, java-server

My HTML code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<p>After submitting such a form the binary multipart form data is available in the HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

afterwards I want to get this file displayed as a post on another page, so help me with that as well.

Comment: Lookup Apache commons file upload. You'll need that unless you're using Spring or some fancy framework.

Comment: I am using Spring (STS).

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Currently i am taking help from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm